# are INTO, FROM an JOIN the only ways to get a table?

Tags: t-sql

I'm currently writing a script which will allow me to input a file (generally .sql) and it'll generate a list of every table that's used in that file. the process is simple as it opened the input file, checks for a substring and if that substring exists outputs the line to the screen.

the substring that being checked is tsql keywords that is indicative of a selected table such as `INTO`, `FROM` and `JOIN`. not being a T-SQL wizard those 3 keywords are the only ones i know of that are used to select a table in a query.

So my question is, in T-SQL are `INTO`, `FROM` an `JOIN` the only ways to get a table? or are these others?

Comment: Don't forget `update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're many ways to get a table, here're some of them:

- `DELETE`
- `FROM`
- `INTO`
- `JOIN`
- [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)
- `OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.mytable', N'U')` where `U` is the object type for table.
- `TABLE`, e.g. [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx), [`DROP TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx)
- `UPDATE`

However, by using your script, you'll not only get real tables, but maybe VIEW and temporary table. Here're 2 examples:

```
-- Example 1
SELECT *
FROM dbo.myview

-- Example 2
WITH tmptable AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT *
FROM tmptable
```